# Remote Control for point and shoot digital camera

Tags: point-and-shoot, remote

Is there a remote control trigger for Point and Shoot digital camera?

I searched the internet and notice that there are only remote control for DSLR camera and phones but not Point and Shoot digital camera.

Comment: What specific model? The is a very real possibility that some do and some don't have remotes available.

Comment: I hope for a universal remote control that can help me to press the camera shutter using wireless or blue tooth remote control. This way, I will not need to consider if the camera support or do not support remotes when buying a new one.

Comment: You won't be able to find that, simply because few point and shoot cameras have any input for a shutter release. You would need some contraption with a motor to press the normal shutter button, and that would need to be very clever in order to fit on multiple models.

Comment: And this, of course, will increase your [balloon weight](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52906/how-to-place-a-light-weight-point-and-shoot-camera-on-a-balloon). It's probably better to look for a camera with this feature built-in, and solve the future when that gets here.

Comment: You might be able to work something out with the CHDK if the camera is a canon. http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are. They are not in the majority because that function is more often associated with advanced users. Not sure what you are looking but if you [search cameras which support wireless triggers](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?remoteinfrared=1&by=feature), there are currently 17 compacts and 3 ultra-compacts.

If you [search for wired-release](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?remotewired=1&by=feature&size=compact), there are just 7 generally pricey compacts. Another option is to [seek cameras with WiFi](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?wifi=1&by=feature). Most WiFi cameras support releasing the shutter wirelessly but often have a good number of additional controls. Those include 23 ultra-compacts and 26 compacts at this time.

Note that the above links are live and will show the current cameras as they appear. Keep checking in a few months (say), if you do not find what you are looking for.